# Is there a convenient solution to go from PDF to excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, power, automation, ocr

I receive these god awful invoices in the form of faxes. We are in the process of implementing EDI however this is how it has to be done for the next few months. The employee i have entering the data is very bored and frustrated. Is there a way to extract the data from this PDF to Excel? I only need the data that is in yellow.

Despite the consistent format things i have tried so far have not worked:

- Adobe DC pro OCR
- Opening the PDF in Word
- Removing everything except the yellow and than trying to convert to Excel

I was thinking power automate however I'm not sure if it is worth the effort vs just outsourcing the data entry.

I am plenty willing to pay if the solution is software

Sample PDF:

[image: Sample PDF]

Comment: It seems hopeless. However, I have to ask - is this a real fax? Real paper with image of table? Or is it still a PDF in which you can highlight individual fields or lines with the cursor when viewing a document in Acrobat Reader? If there is only an image of a scanned paper document inside the PDF, then there is practically no hope. Otherwise, you can try to extract data from the file without loss and distortion.  *There will still be work for the human operator, the extracted data will have to be verified with the original. But it's easier and faster than typing this data from the keyboard)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are the faxes produced on the other side? If they can just send said output as a text file or something, opportunities for automation open up. For example have whichever software produces this send the output to a file or PDF printer on their end. Even if it's some kind of ancient system that uses RS-232, it's still something you could intercept digitally.

Comment: Consider this product.  Decent claims.   ....  https://rossum.ai/lp/OCR/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=search&utm_campaign=ToFu_Conversions_Priority2_adgroup_ocr_pdf&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxc6PBhCEARIsAH8Hff24OTl7QqbhJbA0LcSdxyS7YnU1euALaQAo3WTvQ3jO-yIxeQ0q_HgaAkfOEALw_wcB

Comment: And on another side note, I've not found a reliable means to reproduce tables from OCR yet. As @JohnSUN says, even OCR in general you have to doublecheck, because it might change an important digit, or place a period or comma wrongly.

Comment: There is a [**VBA solution**](https://github.com/decade62/pdf2excel-vba/blob/master/LoadAndConvert.bas) published on Nov 16, 2018 (actually even older). The macro opens the specified PDF file in the viewer, uses SendKeys to copy its contents to the clipboard, closes the viewer, and pastes (parses) the contents of the clipboard into the desired location in the workbook. Perhaps this will be an acceptable solution for you (but only if your PDF files actually contain data and not their scanned image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 has the ability to import data from PDF files directly to Excel

> ## Announcing data import from PDF documents
>
> We are excited to announce a new and exciting update to Get & Transform Data capabilities in Excel – PDF data connector! This has been one of the top requests from you and we heard you. With the new **From PDF** connector you can connect to PDF files, and use the included data from the file, just like any other data source in Excel.
>
> The new **From PDF** connector is available as part of an Office 365 subscription. If you are an Office 365 subscriber, find out how to get the latest updates.
>
> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-data-import-from-pdf-documents/ba-p/1569202

However, as with any PDF converter, it's not in any way 100% reliable because PDF was designed for displaying, not for editing so any text detection can go wrong and you must have manual check after the conversion